# checkbox in while loop as an array and $_POST

Tags: php, html

I have looked through the posts and searching for hours now and i cant find a solution.

The form is in a `while` loop (data pulled from database).
For each result a "row" in a table is formed.
Each Row has  multiple inputs and forms (update, delete etc).
Also now each row has a checkbox.
The checkbox form is the last one so i can place:

```
<input type="submit" value="Delete Selected">
</form>
```

Outside the while loop so the button itself wouldn't loop.

The checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chkdel[<?=$i?>]" value="<?=$accnt[userId]?>">
```

The `$i` is `++$i` in the same `while` loop.

The form for this checkbox:

```
<form method="post" action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>?gm=<?=$gm?>&amp;act=deleteselected">
```

The act is used with `$_REQUEST` to use specific if expression  for the task (Update,delete etc).

However the `$_POST` only has one value in the array. And that value is with the `$i` value as it should be.

Also it only posts a value if the checkbox selected was the last one in the generated list of rows.

```
Array ( [chkdel] => Array ( [3] => bonaxcel03 ) )
```

How would i get it to post all the selected checkbox values instead of the last one?

```
    <tr>
        <form method="post" action="?gm=edit_account&amp;page=1&amp;src=bonaxcel&amp;src_cdn=Account&amp;filter=&amp;act=confirm">
        <input type="hidden" name="usernum" value="150229">
        <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="bonaxcel02">
        <td class="alt1" style="padding: 4px;" width="15%">bonaxcel02</td>
        <td class="alt1" style="padding: 4px; text-align: center;" width="15%">
        <input class="smallinput" type="text" name="userpwd" value="09462921792a"></td>
        <td class="alt1" style="padding: 4px; text-align: center;" width="15%">
        <input class="smallinput" type="text" name="uilock_pw" value="71134744a"></td>
        <td class="alt1" style="padding: 4px; text-align: center;" width="15%">
        <input class="smallinput" type="text" name="usercash" value="5"></td>
        <td class="alt1" style="padding: 4px; text-align: center;" width="20%">2012-12-10 07:11:19           </td>
        <td class="alt1" style="padding: 4px; text-align: center;" width="10%">
        <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn_list_update"></td></form>

        <td class="alt1" style="padding: 4px; text-align: center;" width="10%">         
        <form method="post" action="?gm=edit_account&amp;page=1&amp;src=bonaxcel&amp;src_cdn=Account&amp;filter=&amp;act=delete">
        <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="bonaxcel02">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn_list_delete">
        </form>
        <form method="post" action="?gm=edit_account&amp;page=1&amp;src=bonaxcel&amp;src_cdn=Account&amp;filter=&amp;act=deleteselected">
        <input type="checkbox" name="chkdel[2]" value="bonaxcel02">

        </td>

    </tr>


        <input type="submit" value="Delete Selected">
        </form>
```

This form will repeat for each of the while result (can be thousands on several pages, with filtering options).

Comment: Please post a sample of the _complete_ form as it is output by PHP, from the browser page source.

Comment: The main problem seems to be that the button only posts the value of the last form.

Comment: The first `<form>` looks to be invalid, as it is a direct child of `<tr>` which is not allowed. Only `<td>` or `<th>` can be children of `<tr>`.

Comment: Adding the first form inbetween <TD> tags didn't help, the resulting array is still just the last generated form.
I deleted the first form for testing completely. Same results.

Comment: How about a simpler version of the one above -  just one form for the checkbox, each checkbox would have a xx value and array on the name field.
How would i retrieve the values of all checked boxes wit ha buttonclick. A button outside the loop still only applies to the last one and if its inside a loop, it works for the row where toe button is.
How could it be solved when loops are used (without moving the form declaration outside/before the loop)?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the key as per the results then please use `chkdel[]` insted of `chkdel[<?=$i?>]`